# Is the set of bounded increasing sequences open/closed/compact in the set of all bounded sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

On the set $B =
\{
a ∈ \Bbb R 
 ^\Bbb N |∃C ∈ \Bbb R ∀n ∈ \Bbb N : |a(n)| < C \}$
of all bounded sequences of real
numbers we consider the distance d given by

$d(a, b) = sup \{|a(n) − b(n)| n ∈ \Bbb N \}$

for $a, b ∈ B$. Let$ J = \{a ∈ B |∀n ∈ \Bbb N : a(n + 1) ≥ a(n)\} $be the set of bounded increasing
sequences of real numbers

(a) Is J closed in (B, d)?

(b) Is J open in (B, d)?

(c) Is J compact?

here is my attempt at these three questions

a)My thinking is that it is not closed because it does contain its endpoint C.

b)It is not open Because although it doesn't contain the bound C, it does contain the first term $a_1$.

c)It is not compact because although it is bounded it is not closed.

is that correct or am I thinking about how to do this completely wrong ?

Comment: oh wait because the metric is the supremum of the two points , then it would contain C, wouldn't it so it is closed and it is compact ?

Comment: What do you mean by endpoint in this context?  This is a set of sequences, not a set of numbers.

Comment: The bound C is what I meant

Comment: Each member of $B$ has a bound.  The set $J$ does not have a bound.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I dont understand why that is , arent all the elements in J elements of B aswell ?

Comment: The elements of $J$ are elements of $B$.  Each one has a bound.  The set $J$ does not have a bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a)

As **Robert** said.

If $a\notin J$ then $a(n+1)<a(n)$ for some $n$. 
Now try to find an $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $$d(a,b)<\epsilon\implies b(n+1)<b(n)$$ If you succeed in finding such $\epsilon$ then you have proved that $J^{\complement}$ is open, hence $J$ is closed.

(b)

Note that $\mathbf{0}:=(a_n)_n\in J$ when $a_n=0$ for each $n$. If $J$ is open then some $\epsilon>0$ must exist with $B(\mathbf0,\epsilon)\subseteq J$. Can you find one (or can you prove that such $\epsilon$ does not exist)?

(c)

$J=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(J\cap B(\mathbf0,n))$ where the sets $J\cap B(\mathbf0,n)$ are open in $J$. Is there a finite subcover ?

---

**edit**:

a) addendum.

From $|a_k-b_k|\leq d(a,b)$ for each $k$ it follows directly that $b_{n+1}\leq a_{n+1}+d(a,b)$ and $a_n-d(a,b)\leq b_n$.

If e.g. $d(a,b)<\frac13(a_n-a_{n+1})$ then we also have $a_{n+1}+d(a,b)<a_n-d(a,b)$ leading to $b_{n+1}<b_n$.

We conclude that $J^{\complement}$ is open, hence $J$ is closed.

b) addendum

If $\epsilon>0$ then $B(\mathbf0,\epsilon)$ will contain the sequence $(b_n)_n$ prescribed by $b_1=0$ and $b_n=-\frac12\epsilon$ for $n>1$, which is not an element of $J$.

We conclude that $J$ is not open.

c) addendum

If we take a finite number of sets out of $\{J\cap B(\mathbf0,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ then the union of these sets will take the form $J\cap B(\mathbf0,m)$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$. However, it is evident that $J\cap B(\mathbf0,m)\neq J$ so apparantly there is no finite subcover.

We conclude that $J$ is not compact.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to use open balls with sequences, is there any webpages you could recommend to help me better understand ?

Comment: I think that a webpage focused on "balls and sequences" is hard to find. This because no essential difficulties arise. I can only say: don't allow the sequences to square you off, and just look at them as elements of a metric space. The ball $B(\mathbf0,\epsilon)$ mentioned in my answer contains all sequences $a=(a_n)_n$ that satisfy $d(\mathbf0,a)=\sup|a_n|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I think I understand what you've done now for part a) basically youve found a point a which is not in J and then youve said if there is an open ball between it and any other point not in J then $ J^C $ is open ? then if the distance is the supremum this implies there is no epsilon we can find , so the compliment is closed and hence J is open in B, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If a set ($J^{\complement}$) is open then its complement ($J$) is closed. That is direct and needs no further arguing.

Answer (score 3):

For (a), what you should be thinking about is, given a member $a$ of $B$ that is not in $J$, is there a ball around $a$ that is disjoint from $J$?

Comment: im not sure how to use balls with sequences but could we use this theorem i found ? A set A in a metric space (X,d) is closed iff i) $ \{ x_n \} $ ii) $ x_n \to x \in X $ $ \Rightarrow x \in A $ ? and then surmise that J is closed because it contains the limit to any convergent sequence in it ?

Comment: Remember, there are two different kinds of sequences at work here.  The members of $B$ are sequences of real numbers.  The sequence $x_n$ in your criterion is a sequence of members of $B$, thus a sequence of sequences.

Comment: But I think it is better to use balls in this case.  A set $A$ in a metric space is closed iff its complement $A^c$ is open, i.e. iff for every $x \in A^c$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B_\epsilon(x) = \{y: d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$ is contained in $A^c$.